# Android INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION while installing apk on emulator

Tags: android

I created a debug apk (on Windows) from command line using

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

When I try to install it on a emulator using

```
adb install app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

I get following message:

```
1057 KB/s (419548 bytes in 0.387s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]
```

I ran `adb logcat` in a separate terminal window and it shows below trace:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(  203): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  203): CheckJNI is ON
D/AndroidRuntime(  203): --- registering native functions ---
D/ddm-heap(  203): Got feature list request
D/PackageParser(   52): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl65951.tmp
W/ResourceType(   52): Bad string block: string #1 extends to 2847, past end at 68
W/PackageParser(   52): /data/app/vmdl65951.tmp
W/PackageParser(   52): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString(Native Method)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:81)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.content.res.AssetManager.getPooledString(AssetManager.java:258)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:675)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getValueAt(TypedArray.java:659)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.content.res.TypedArray.peekValue(TypedArray.java:620)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApplication(PackageParser.java:1351)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:734)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:390)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:4275)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.access$1600(PackageManagerService.java:109)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at com.android.server.PackageManagerService$5.run(PackageManagerService.java:3779)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/PackageParser(   52):         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
D/AndroidRuntime(  203): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(  203): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
D/dalvikvm(  203): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
```

How can I fix this?

My `build.gradle` looks like below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 7
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myApp"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
```

and my `AndroidManifest.xml` is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myApp"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="2" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayForm"
            class=".Aarti" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` 27 with `buildToolsVersion` 27 in `build.gradle`

Comment: I am able to compile and install my app on a device using compileSdkVersion 7. Its only while running it on an emulator (API level 7) that I am getting this error. I suspect its a problem with the emulator.

Comment: compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, targetSdkVersion should match

Comment: @ico2k2 beside the speculative fix, do you know why the error is happening in the first place?

Comment: I don't know why the error is happening but Android Studio recommends to put the same version for `compileSdkVersion` `targetSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`